# TYPO3 how to extend or add flux:field.inline.fal an additional input field

Tags: typo3

Hello im trying to add additional option fields to my image they should be binded to the props anybody an idea how i can manage this issue? i have to access them by fileReference.caption if is it possible.

```
   <f:section name="Configuration">
  <flux:form id="tsi_seitenteaser" label="Slider" description="Zeigt den Seitenteaser an" options="{icon: '/typo3conf/ext/tsi_site/Resources/Public/Backend/img/Seitenteaser.png'}">
     <flux:field.inline.fal name="SlideSideteaser" maxItems="30" allowedExtensions="jpg,png,svg" label="Slider Sideteaser"/>
     <flux:field.input name="caption" label="Caption"/>
     <flux:field.input name="text" label="Text"/>
  </flux:form>
```

Comment: Do you have your own extension or FCE?

Comment: Look, fal - its multy lines. Event you will add input to inline.fal will be mess. Cause very important have just one uploaded image, then add text just to this entity. As for me its really bad idea. Better add them separatly with same identify - like via  <flux:grid> and inside flux:field.file and flux:field.text  - so you will able get all by one Object. If you interest this approche i can add example

Comment: Oleg yeah sure show me that solution and @TYPO3 Learner its my own! but is it possible to extend fce?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot extend the TCA of `sys_file_reference` via a Flux element, and that's what you would need to do in order to render those fields associated with each individual reference. Flux can do a lot of things, but it cannot do things that TYPO3 doesn't support and this would be one such thing (it's essentially the same as doing this via a standard FlexForm field).

The alternative, as Oleg hints to, would be to create sections with objects inside and define one non-IRRE field with a file reference and X number of additional fields. I don't recommend this solution as file relations from FlexForms are notoriously error prone when combined with section objects (due to the problem determining a true ID for the origin side of the relation, which then becomes too broadly associated with the entire FlexForm field instead of the individual section objects).

Even so: you already have the fields you need as actual TCA fields on `sys_file` (on earlier versions of TYPO3 this requires `EXT:filemetadata` to be installed). I strongly suggest you use those fields and if you need additional ones, extend the TCA of the `sys_file_reference` table to include whichever fields you like.